# Rewrite to another address showing the entered URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect:

Entered URL:

`http://localhost/Test/Test1/key/val`

To the following address, but showing the previous URL:

`http://localhost/Test/Test1/Test1.php?key=val`

The `.htaccess` file is at `/Test`.

I have this, but always get the HTTP error `404 NOT FOUND`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([\w]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /%1.php?%2=%3 [L]
```

I have searched for this but could not find a similar problem solved.

I will appreciate any help to make the appropriate modifications to the rules

Comment: Any specifics could be found in the apache error log. If you have access to that, it is most likely in /var/log/apache/error.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several issues in your rules.

.1 The rewrite condition regex does not match.

.2 If the entered URI has a trailing slash, the script won't get the query string because `val` becomes `val/`

.3 There is nothing to prevent a loop.

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)[^/]*/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([\w]+)/? [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php  [NC]
RewriteRule .*  %1/%2/%2.php?%3=%4 [L]
```

Hope that's what you need.

Comment: It does it. I was taking my time trying to understand why your rules work and what's wrong with mine and my conclusion is I had almost everything wrong. Really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([\w]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /Test1/%1.php?%2=%3 [L]
```